# What's the syntax of "purport"?

Tags: word-usage, syntactic-analysis

I keep reading in some style/usage books that "purport" shouldn't be turned *passive* because the sense of the verb is "already passive." Thus,

> Three people were arrested Sunday at the Smithsonian Institution's Air and Space Museum after pouring what *was purported* [read *purported*] to be human blood and ashes on the Enola Gay. ([*Garner's Modern English Usage*](https://books.google.com/books?id=l2LmCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA755&dq=is%20purported%20usage&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiu3_Wy9s7bAhUB64MKHcWED2kQ6AEIUjAH#v=onepage&q=is%20purported%20usage&f=false), 4th edition, by Bryan Garner)

Apparently, the objection goes back to H.W. Fowler, who, in *Modern English Usage* said that this verb should never be used in the passive.

So, I wonder: for linguists, what is the syntax of *purport*? How does it work? Garner in the example above objects to "what was purported to be," but that actually sounds ok to me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Whatever it's origin, the usage in the passage you gave sounds correct to me. So, maybe its usage has changed and it's now acceptable.

Comment: @JasonBassford I agree. And I don't see the point about the "sense of the verb being already passive". "The newcomer purported to be an expert." seems a normal active voice sentence to me.

Comment: Who is doing the action (the purporting)?  It's not specified.  Just as "was built in 1933" would be used when the builder wasn't specified.

Comment: Presumably "the Enola Gray" is a typo.

Comment: ***Purport***: If you say that someone or something purports to do or be a particular thing, you mean that they claim to do or be that thing, although you may not always believe that claim. https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/purport

Comment: @HotLicks In my example the person who did the purporting was "the newcomer" - the subject of the sentence.

Comment: @WS2 - I was asking Puzzled, in his example.

Comment: @WS2 I can't say that. It's glaringly wrong to me. You can't purport yourself to be something. *Purport* has do to with how something was advertised or represented to be, but always by some unnamed third party source, not by oneself. *The purported expert none the less ...* or *the newcomer, purportedly regarded an expert, none the less ...*

Comment: @WS2 from [MW's dictionary of synonyms](https://books.google.com/books?id=8N4UReTJYhUC&lpg=PA802&dq=%22purported%22&pg=PA802#v=onepage&q=%22purported%22&f=false) - "but especially in its common journalistic use the word tends to stress the writer's disclaimer of the responsibility for the matter asserted". This explains why one can't purport oneself to be something. *Purport* invokes an anonymous outside agent who's characterization is not subscribed to by the speaker.

Comment: @PhilSweet I would certainly agree that that is the way in which it is more often employed. However OED sense 1b shows that it is used in an active sense too. *1984   A. Carter Nights at Circus i. i. 17   In a secular age, an authentic miracle must purport to be a hoax.* Personally I see nothing wrong with *He purports to have the requisite authority*, and have used it in that way myself. It carries a different sense to "he pretends" which conveys falsity. "He purports" leaves the matter of authenticity open.